# Mac snow leopard - check what devices is hooked up to USB

Tags: usb

How can I check what are the USB devices I currently have hooked up to my mac?
I went to the "System Profiler" and click on USB.
It shows built in devices but doesn't seem like it shows devices like my external mouse etc?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mouse, etc are probably tucked away in a USB Bus/Hub, and it may have a name like "USB Receiver".